# mysql2 on Windows

Tags: ruby, redmine, mysql2

I'm trying to install redmine 5.0.5 on Window Server2016
using ruby 3.1.4、mysql 5.7.42

When I enter the command "gem install mysql2" in the command prompt.

He return an error "Could not create Makefile due to some reason; probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may need configuration options."

And then I go to see the mkmf.log,

I see the error about `'error: rb_wait_for_single_fd' undeclared(first use in this function)` and
`error: 'rb_enc_interned_str' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'rb_interned_str'`

I think I may need to install the MySQL C API, but when I downloaded it and extracted it, there was only one folder, and I don't know how to install it.